# Eclipse (Aptana-Studio) - strange transparency areas on the IDE

Tags: eclipse, ide

I have no idea how to explain you what do I mean, but take a look at the screenshot, as it might allow you to understand my situation a bit better: [screenshot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cxXya.png)

I am using Ubuntu 10.04 i386.

Does anyone have any idea how could I have caused this, and how can I fix it?

Just a note, I've had tried to install some custom color schemes for eclipse manually, but at that time I haven't experienced such issues...

Comment: This question appears to be abandoned, if you are experiencing a similar issue please [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) with details pertaining to your problem. If you feel this question is *not* abandoned, please flag the question explaining that. :)

Answer (score 0):

Try reinstalling `eclipse`, and also `java` if needed.

Maybe the color scheme is not made for Ubuntu.

Yours,
Daniel